# regex not matching in findText()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I was trying to change color to some text in a document, and I required regexp.
So, I tried the function `findText` to search where my text is in the selected text, but I am having some troubles matching the regexps.

Look at this sample script

```
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Test')
      .addItem('Find regex in sel', 'findRegex'))
      .addToUi();
}

function findRegex() {
    var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
    var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
    var txt = selection.getSelectedElements()[0].getElement().asText();
    var inp = ui.prompt('Regex to search:').getResponseText();
    var regex = new RegExp(inp);
    ui.alert('Found in "' + txt.getText()
           + '"\n  Re: ' + txt.findText(regex)
           + '\n  In: ' + txt.findText(inp));
}
```

This prompts for something to search, then builds a regex out of it. Then both the regex and the original string are used to search in the selected text.

Well, I do not know what to do to get the `regex` matching: I am always getting null: if the text to be searched is "foobarbaz", and I input `foo`, only the plain string matches.
If instead I input `/foo/`, clearly nothing matches.

How should I use regexps to search using `findText`?
Consider that I have to "compose" regex, like `/foobar/ + /\d+/`, where `foobar` is the user-entered pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think to have found the crux: the regexp passed to `findText` is *always* a String object, even if it have a regexp inside.

I tried searching `"fo+"` in the text `"fooo"` and it matched correctly.

Comment: as stated in the documentation indeed : [see here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body?hl=fr-FR#findText(String)) +1 to have found it by yourself ;-)